# Adding columns for List<T> inside of a mode class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a data model for `DataGridView` and inside this model there is `List<T>` property. But `DataGridView` doesn't display that `List<T>` property. It displays other properties but it doesn't display `List<T>` property.

Here is code:

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<NotModeli> Notlar;
    public Form1()
    {
        Notlar = new List<NotModeli>()
        {
            new NotModeli()
            {
                dersAdi = "Hukuk",
                vizeNotu = 78,
                araSinav = new List<int>{50},
                finalNotu = 98
            }
        };

        InitializeComponent();
        veriPaneli.DataSource = Notlar;
    }
}

public class NotModeli
{
    public string dersAdi { get; set; }
    public int vizeNotu { get; set; }
    public List<int> araSinav { get; set; }
    public int finalNotu { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How would you like to display that list in the DGV?

Comment: For instance araSinav as Headers and values inside the List<T>. Can't i do that?

Comment: How would you like the list to be displayed in _one cell_? Do you want to join its values?

Comment: So you want to display *nested data*. How did you expect that to look? The grid view can display nested (master/detail) data as a nested table under the master row, but the result is pretty ugly and in this case, unsuitable. You can specify a custom column but perhaps the easiest solution would be to create a getter that returns the joined IDs as a string, eg `araSinav_Values=>String.Join(",",araSinav);`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I want each values inside `List<int>` in the model to be displayed in seperated cells and the Headers as 'araSinav'.

Comment: @YarkinGulacti separate top-level columns? How is the grid going to guess how many columns to add? What if there's a different number of values in each row? How would they be named? Your question may seem simple but it's actually complex and right now, unclear

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as i said to Mr. Ahmed, i want different columns for the values inside the `List<int>`.

Comment: @YarkinGulacti Well, you could theoretically do that and merge the header's cells but a list can have an arbitrary number of elements. Are you sure you want to create one cell for each element as opposed to joining them and place them in one cell?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes you're right, i should've thought about it. I guess need to figure out some other way.

Comment: @YarkinGulacti Did you check my answer below? Perhaps that's an alternative solution to consider.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed i guess nested way is what should i do, thanks for the replies.

Comment: @YarkinGulacti you need to decide what you want to display first. If you know the number of columns you can flatten your data and produce an extra property per "column". DGV isn't very sophisticated but it does allow some customisations. End users may not like the end result though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to join the elements of the list and display them in one cell, a simple way to go about this would be to create a read-only property that returns the joined elements as string. Your class would look something like this:

```
public class NotModeli
{
    public string dersAdi { get; set; }
    public int vizeNotu { get; set; }
    public List<int> araSinav { get; set; }
    
    public int finalNotu { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("araSinav")]
    public string JoinedAraSinav => string.Join(",", araSinav);
}
```

---

Now, since we're dealing with numbers, joining them with a comma might not look good. We can use a similar approach to display them in the form of a table (still inside one cell).

First, configure your DataGridView as follows: <sup>(you can do that manually using the designer)</sup>

```
veriPaneli.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

var dersAdiCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "dersAdi",
    DataPropertyName = "dersAdi"
};
var vizeNotuCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "vizeNotu",
    DataPropertyName = "vizeNotu"
};
var araSinavCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "araSinav",
    DataPropertyName = "JoinedAraSinav",
    Width = 220
};
araSinavCol.DefaultCellStyle.Font = 
    new Font("Consolas", veriPaneli.Font.Size, veriPaneli.Font.Style);
var finalNotuCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    HeaderText = "finalNotu",
    DataPropertyName = "finalNotu"
};

veriPaneli.Columns.AddRange(dersAdiCol, vizeNotuCol, araSinavCol, finalNotuCol);
```

Then, change the `JoinedAraSinav` property to something like the following:

```
[DisplayName("araSinav")]
public string JoinedAraSinav => 
    string.Join(" | ", araSinav.Select(i => i.ToString("00000")));
//                                                      ^^^^^
// The number of zeros controls the padding of the displayed numbers.
```

**End result:**

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thank you Sir! That's what i'm going to do.

Comment: @YarkinGulacti Check the update that I made to the answer.